# Internet Explorer 11 wobbly CSS3 animation

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

Please refer to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eQegA/3/

```
<div class="spinner"></div>

.spinner {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 50px solid blue;
    /*border-top-color: #fff;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;*/ /* commented out to see the wobble better */
    border-radius: 200px;    

    -webkit-animation: application-loading-rotate 1s;
    animation: application-loading-rotate 1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes application-loading-rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes application-loading-rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

In Google Chrome the rotation is stable, however for some reason in IE11 there is a noticable "wobble" of the circle as it rotates.

Any ideas why it wobbles so?  Is there any way to fix it in IE11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what it's worth, it also occurs on other browsers. It has to do, how the border is drawn, it's not a perfect round. As far as I know, there isn't a quick fix for this. However you can draw the border as a background image.

```
.spinner {
display:block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-image:url(http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/9iR/RyK/9iRRyKLie.png);
    background-size:100%;

    -webkit-animation: application-loading-rotate 1s;
    animation: application-loading-rotate 1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes application-loading-rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes application-loading-rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

See:
http://jsfiddle.net/eQegA/26/

Comment: Thanks Mark.  The .png rendering is quite dithered and isn't good enough quality.  It's given me an idea though to use SVG for the arc instead which appears to render and rotate quite nicely in IE11.

Comment: Yes, SVG will do nicely. PNG was just an example.