# Wobbly CSS Animation with Border-Radius in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-animations

In Internet Explorer this animation appears to wobble. I was reading the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566831/internet-explorer-11-wobbly-css3-animation) and they made it sound as though it is possible to fix.

I cannot really use an image as the border radius is not constant, and I would prefer not to use an animated gif.

I understand 'wobble' is not a very good description but I can't think of any other words to describe it. I have not tested it with Opera/Safari, so if you have either of them I would like to know if they display correctly or also have the problem. Please run the following Snippet in Chrome/Firefox and compare it to the Snippet in Internet Explorer:

```css
@keyframes spin{
 0% {transform:rotateZ(0deg);}
 50% {transform:rotateZ(360deg);border-radius:60%;}
 100%{transform:rotateZ(720deg);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin{
 0% {transform:rotateZ(0deg);}
 50% {transform:rotateZ(360deg);border-radius:60%;}
 100%{transform:rotateZ(720deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes spin{
 0% {transform:rotateZ(0deg);}
 50% {transform:rotateZ(360deg);border-radius:60%;}
 100%{transform:rotateZ(720deg);}
}
@-ms-keyframes spin{
 0% {transform:rotateZ(0deg);}
 50% {transform:rotateZ(360deg);border-radius:60%;}
 100%{transform:rotateZ(720deg);}
}
@-o-keyframes spin{
 0% {transform:rotateZ(0deg);}
 50% {transform:rotateZ(360deg);border-radius:60%;}
 100%{transform:rotateZ(720deg);}
}
#spinme{
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 margin:0.2rem;
 width:0.8rem;
 height:0.8rem;
 border:0.2rem solid black;
 border-radius:0;
 outline: 1px solid transparent; /* require to remove jagged edges in firefox */
 transform:rotateZ(0deg);
 animation: spin infinite 4s;
 -webkit-animation: spin infinite 4s;
 -moz-animation: spin infinite 4s;
 -ms-animation: spin infinite 4s;
 -o-animation: spin infinite 4s;
}
#spinme:nth-child(2){animation-delay:0.06s}
#spinme:nth-child(3){animation-delay:0.12s}
#spinme:nth-child(4){animation-delay:0.18s}
```

```html
<div id="spinme"></div>
<div id="spinme"></div>
<div id="spinme"></div>
<div id="spinme"></div>
```

The `outline` hack to fix the sharp edge came from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9333891/4907552).

---

As a side question, and out of curiosity, which of those prefixes are actually required? I was looking at the [compatibility requirements](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)  to get it working in older browsers, but it only ever mentions the `-webkit` prefix: none of the `-moz`,`-ms` or `-o` prefixes seem to be needed for any browser version.

I have also just checked [shouldiprefix](http://shouldiprefix.com/#animations) and they seem to agree with caniuse, but given how similar the names are I thought that the same community/company may run both websites. Should I just remove the other prefixes?

Comment: Very strange and interesting question. I would say its kind of *shivering* :)

Comment: I tried some things and I ended up making suggestion that the reason of the circles are "wobbly" or shaking is the matter of engine that render radius border. I also saw wobbly effect when I tried to zoom the circle when I run the codes over Chrome. Better anti-aliasing on chrome, perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it is the transparent outline interfering with the edge of the object. The outline is always a square (as you can see by using `outline: 1px solid blue;` for example). I can only assume that using a 1px transparent outline outline over an interpolated circular shape causes the rendering issue.

Replacing `outline:1px solid transparent;` with `outline:1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);` **or** `outline:0 solid transparent;` fixes Edge and IE11 for me. I don't have Firefox so I cannot test if this also removed the jagged edges still.

```css
@keyframes spin{
    0% {transform:rotateZ(0deg);}
    50% {transform:rotateZ(360deg);border-radius:60%;}
    100%{transform:rotateZ(720deg);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin{
    0% {transform:rotateZ(0deg);}
    50% {transform:rotateZ(360deg);border-radius:60%;}
    100%{transform:rotateZ(720deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes spin{
    0% {transform:rotateZ(0deg);}
    50% {transform:rotateZ(360deg);border-radius:60%;}
    100%{transform:rotateZ(720deg);}
}
@-ms-keyframes spin{
    0% {transform:rotateZ(0deg);}
    50% {transform:rotateZ(360deg);border-radius:60%;}
    100%{transform:rotateZ(720deg);}
}
@-o-keyframes spin{
    0% {transform:rotateZ(0deg);}
    50% {transform:rotateZ(360deg);border-radius:60%;}
    100%{transform:rotateZ(720deg);}
}
#spinme{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0.2rem;
    width:0.8rem;
    height:0.8rem;
    border:0.2rem solid black;
    border-radius:0;
    outline:0 solid transparent;
    transform:rotateZ(0deg);
    animation: spin infinite 4s;
    -webkit-animation: spin infinite 4s;
    -moz-animation: spin infinite 4s;
    -ms-animation: spin infinite 4s;
    -o-animation: spin infinite 4s;
}
```

```html
<div id="spinme"></div>
```

As for the vendor prefix part, when I was testing locally I see that IE11 and Edge both support the prefix-less `animation: spin infinite 4s;` but IE11 still supports `-ms-animation`. Edge does not supports `-ms-animation` but does support `-webkit-animation` - see [Will Microsoft Edge use prefixes like -webkit- or -ms-?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30824665/637889). So depending on your target browser audience you can choose to leave out deprecated properties if you wish, although I would leave them all for now so that older browsers are not excluded.

**Note:** I did see that toggling CSS properties in the Edge inspector showed the calculated `border-[top|bottom]-[left|right]-radius` properties were sometimes a percentage and sometimes a hard `px` value. I'm not sure this is related or relevant to the problem though.

Comment: That is insane. What's even stranger is that `outline:0 solid transparent;` fixes the bug in IE but reintroduces the sharp edges in Firefox. And yet, somehow, `outline:1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);` fixes both! So technically, it's the definition of `transparent` that causes such a weird rendering error?

Comment: Oh nice, I'm glad one of the solutions fits all browsers. I was equally as surprised since [`transparent`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparent) should be shorthand for `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`, which also works if you keep the `1px` with `outline:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: It's so peculiar, but seeing as this question has been solved, and the conversion is a different question, I've decided to ask about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32479188/whats-the-difference-between-rgba0-0-0-0-and-transparent).

Answer (score 1):

To fix the IE Internet Explorer bug where rotating things causes a wobble, try this. The **transform-origin** should be set to half the width in all dimensions(x, y and z).

If your element is 40px wide and tall, set the properties like this:

```
transform-origin: 20px 20px 20px;
```